# Hot deploy not longer working on JBoss ("Scheme change not implemented")

Tags: java, jboss, hotdeploy

I've got a pretty annoying problem with my JBoss AS 4.2.3 GA.

Until recently everything was running fine, but now the hot deploy feature is now longer working. And -- as always -- I don't know what I did to cause this behaviour.

My projects are built with Maven. I've cleaned every target directory, installed the projects and then deployed them to the server. So the sources in Eclipse and the deployed projects on the server should be identical.
Inside a method I've added a simple `System.out.println("test");` statement and -- BANG! -- I get the following error:

[image: Hot code replace failed - Scheme change not implemented]
<sub>(source: [imagefruity.com](http://imagefruity.com/images/92236289746667737609.png))</sub>

Do you know a way out of my trouble?

Comment: I'll take "Details>>" for $100, Alex.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. :-(

Comment: I think Alex is saying "What happens when you click 'Details >>' on the screenshot?"

Comment: A little window opens with "Scheme change not implemented" written in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I did the following things now:

1. Uninstall all JDKs
2. Install only one JDK, namely JDK5 (cause that's the one we use in production)
3. Clean, install and deploy every project anew

And now it seems to work (I'm keeping my fingers crossed).

I've used JDK 6 Update 20 for building in Eclipse and JDK 6 Update 7 in Maven. Maybe that has caused the problem.

Comment: 4. Make sure that you don't have any project-specific compile settings under Project Properties -> Java Compiler. That seems to have been a problem in my environment.

Answer (score 6):

In my case "Hot code replace failed - Scheme change not implemented" was caused by IDE using another compiler than compiler used to build files deployed on J2EE server. You can binary compare class files in your J2EE archive with class files compiled by IDE in your workspace - they should be identical.

For details please [check here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150724122312/http://wiki.dirigent-mda.com/java/j2ee-hot-code-replace).