# Finding class files that Eclipse builds

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, build, .class-file

When Eclipse builds my workspace, I assume that it creates Java .class files. What else should otherwise deploy to my running JBoss AS?

Do you know where I can find these class files that Eclipse temporarily creates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click on your project, and then click on properties.  Now click on the Java Build Path section, and you will be able to see and set the Default output folder on the "Source" tab.  I believe Eclipse defaults to "bin"

More than likely though, it won't be enough to just copy these over to JBoss.  You'll need to deploy your application as a .war file, which is basically a .zip with a different extension.  Do some googling on "ant war task" for some examples and articles.

Comment: Actually I want to check the class files of Eclipse and the ones in my JBoss deploy directory for differences since hot deploy is no longer working on my JBoss (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005919/hot-deploy-not-longer-working-on-jbos )

Answer (score 1):

As gregcase has said, you want to deploy a .war file, and if you want Eclipse to do this for you, just right-click on the project, select "export" and under "web" choose "WAR file."

Copy this file to $JBOSS_HOME/server/default/deploy/ and you should be set.

Comment: See comment to gregcase answer please.