# Hot deploy fails on JBoss - "Delete method not implemented"

Tags: java, maven-2, jboss, java-6, jboss-4.2.x

When I'm changing some Java source code and my server is running, hot deploy fails, giving the following error message:

> "Delete method not implemented"

How can I find out the root of this evil? My project has been recently deployed, so the sources on the server should be up to date.

---

The project uses JSF 1.2, if that's of any use for you.

---

I deploy the project as an exploded war.

---

Won't work with a zipped war either.

---

It's strange that the sources of dependencies are also not resolved in the debug mode. They're correctly read from the jar in the Eclipse Java view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005919/hot-deploy-not-longer-working-on-jboss-scheme-change-not-implemented) more than one year ago. And [my answer to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005919/hot-deploy-not-longer-working-on-jboss-scheme-change-not-implemented/3012870#3012870) solved this problem too.

1. Uninstall all JDKs
2. Install only on JDK
3. Configure every program (Eclipse and JBoss) to use this JDK.

Answer (score 0):

if you 'touch' the file (war/ear) in the deploy directory, this should trigger the deployment cycle, is this happening?

Comment: if you have this deployed to Unix, then in the directory, type 'touch my.war' or something like that, should be enough to trigger the deployer, also what application server are you using?

Comment: If got this deployed under Windows. I'm using JBoss 4.2.3.

Comment: HI, can you print the stack trace, it would help, what happens when you stop and start the server, does it deploy correctly then. Are you sure you have the correct deployer configured in Jboss?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435/windows-version-of-the-unix-touch-command this thread shows you how to touch a file on Windows.

Comment: This `Delete method not implemented` is the whole "stack trace" in Eclipse. :-(

Comment: OK, so you are deploying from Eclipse to a JBOSS server implementation in Eclipse, so you are programming and testing on a server configuration. I suppose you see the console output for the jboss server starting, but then when you look at your deployed app you get that message Delete method not implemented??? I think you need to post some more information, as its hard to know exactly what you are doing.